Appropriate analysis to determine who benefits more and less form a program
Around 150 participants attended a 3 months program (no control group).
I have their scores before and after the program on several measures (T1 and  T2).
Participants went to a program in 4 different institutions.
I am interested in finding out what kind of participants (considering several variables - dummy, ordinal and scale) benefit more or less form this program.
What kind of analysis would you suggest?

A mixed model is probably a good guess.

Thank you for your replay. How would you treat the time variable considering there are only 2 time points? Is this a problems for mixed-models?

This is no different than a paired test, before/after comparison. Time in this case would probably be discrete, "before" vs "after" category.
